# Ag-grid (Community Version) Pagination Text Custom

Tags: ag-grid

with the Ag-grid (Community Version) with filtering enabled, I would like to customize the Pagination text.

If the grid has five rows the standard pagination text is: 1 to 5 of 5

With no filtering applied, I would like the pagination text to be: Showing 1 to 5 entries.

With filtering applied and 2 rows qualify, I would like the pagination text to be: Showing 1 to 2 entries (filtered from 5 total entries).

Can someone please help with this? I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using ag-Grid's native pagination controls. Best solution would be to create your own custom pagination controls and display your desired text there.

Comment: Thank you ViqMontana, much appreciated.